# Slider navigators working very slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As I am new to JQuery, I was recently practicing it by creating a simple slider with navigation buttons.

The entire slider is working correctly but the navigation buttons are responding very slowly. When I am clicking on them for the first time, I need to click them twice to make them respond. There is no error on the console. Everything is working correctly, except the navigation button response time.

Thank you for the help in advance.

```js
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
var slider_count = 1;
var offset_value;
start();

function left() {

  slider_count--;
  if (slider_count < 0) {
    slider_count = slides.length - 1;
  }
  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);

}

function right() {


  if (slider_count >= slides.length) {
    slider_count = 0;
  }
  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);
  slider_count++;
}

function start() {


  if (slider_count == slides.length) {
    slider_count = 0;
  }

  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  slider_count++;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(start, 3000);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slide-option-1 {
  background-color: #808080;
}

#slide-option-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#slide-option-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-1 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 45%;
}

#nav-2 {
  right: 10px;
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <a id="nav-1" onclick="left()" class="nav">Left</a>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slide-option-1" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-option-2" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-option-3" class="slide"></div>
  </div>
  <a id="nav-2" class="nav" onclick="right()">Right</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

initialize `slider_count` with `0`.

```js
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
var slider_count = 0;
var offset_value;
start();

function left() {

  slider_count--;
  if (slider_count < 0) {
    slider_count = slides.length - 1;
  }
  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);

}

function right() {

  slider_count++;
  if (slider_count >= slides.length) {
    slider_count = 0;
  }
  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);
}

function start() {

  slider_count++;
  if (slider_count >= slides.length) {
    slider_count = 0;
  }

  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(start, 3000);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slide-option-1 {
  background-color: #808080;
}

#slide-option-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#slide-option-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-1 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 45%;
}

#nav-2 {
  right: 10px;
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <a id="nav-1" onclick="left()" class="nav">Left</a>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slide-option-1" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-option-2" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-option-3" class="slide"></div>
  </div>
  <a id="nav-2" class="nav" onclick="right()">Right</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

increase  `setTimeout(start, 9000);` so it will slow

```js
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide');
var slider_count = 1;
var offset_value;
start();

function left() {
  slider_count--;
  if (slider_count < 0) {
      slider_count = slides.length - 1;
  }

  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
      scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 100);

}

function right() {
  if (slider_count >= slides.length) {
    slider_count = 0;
  }

  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 100);
  slider_count++;
}

function start() {
  if (slider_count == slides.length) {
    slider_count = 0;
  }

  offset_value = slides[slider_count].offsetLeft;
  slider_count++;
  $("#wrapper").animate({
    scrollLeft: offset_value
  }, 1000);
  setTimeout(start, 9000);
}
```

```css
html,
body,
body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#slide-option-1 {
  background-color: #808080;
}

#slide-option-2 {
  background-color: green;
}

#slide-option-3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

#main {
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-1 {
  left: 10px;
  top: 45%;
}

#nav-2 {
  right: 10px;
  top: 45%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <a id="nav-1" onclick="left()" class="nav">Left</a>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="slide-option-1" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-option-2" class="slide"></div>
    <div id="slide-option-3" class="slide"></div>
  </div>
  <a id="nav-2" class="nav" onclick="right()">Right</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry. But still the navigation buttons respond very slowly.

Comment: Improved a little bit. But still sometimes need to click twice on the navigation buttons.

Comment: b'coz of you use timeout and function for it thats why it perform slow